# How to get all the data using match query in single hit from elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using PHP elasticsearch client and getting all the matched data from elasticsearch using following code.

```
$sponsorSearch['index'] = 'sponsors';
$sponsorSearch['type'] = 'couchbaseDocument';
$sponsorSearch['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['eventid'] = $EventID;
$sponsorSearch['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['paystatus'] = "complete";
$sponsorCount = $client->count($sponsorSearch);
if($sponsorCount['count']>0) {
   $sponsorSearch['from'] = 0;
   $sponsorSearch['size'] = $sponsorCount['count'];
   $sponsorResponse = $client->search($sponsorSearch);
}
```

But it uses two hits to elasticsearch, one for count the number of documents and other is to fetch the documents. I want to perform this in a single hit only.

Comment: You simply want to get all results from your index? How many documents are we talking about?

Comment: There are more than 10 matching documents in my index, and i want to retrieve all of them in a single hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than 10 documents (but less than, say, 10000), you can simply specify a bigger size than 10 in your query and only do a search (i.e. no count query):

```
$sponsorSearch['index'] = 'sponsors';
$sponsorSearch['type'] = 'couchbaseDocument';
$sponsorSearch['size'] = 1000;
$sponsorSearch['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['eventid'] = $EventID;
$sponsorSearch['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['paystatus'] = "complete";
$sponsorResponse = $client->search($sponsorSearch);
```

Comment: But as i know we should not hard coded the size parameter, assuming that we have less than 1000 record is not a good practice, in many cases it may be exceeded

Comment: It makes no difference, if you have less docs, that will have no impact... you're only telling ES "give me all the docs you have that match the criteria as I neither want to get the count nor paginate the results, trust me I won't bog you down"

Comment: Thanks @Val, i used this but i think after at a time when there are more documents, it leads to be an error

Comment: You want to do it in one hit but you don't want to take shortcuts :) Not sure how I can help you...

Comment: Did you find another way around or are still doing two queries?

Comment: I am doing the same as you said, i didn't find a better way to do this

Comment: Ideally, it would be nice if one could specify `size: "all"` and ES would return 103 documents if there are 103 documents, 1562 documents if there are 1562 documents, etc. Until then, my answer above is the only way I know that can satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Getting all the hits at once has a very small number of practical applications and is very inefficient and takes a long time if there are tens of thousands of results because of the distributed nature of elasticsearch. I suggest you evaluate why exactly you want to do this and if there are any possible alternatives.

Although if you still want to get all the result for some reason there's only one other way than what you are doing right now and that is using the scroll API. I am not sure how exactly the php API works but you can take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html).

The only other solution that I see you are not very keen on is setting an absurdly high size like a million. By default the limit on the size of result is 10000, but you can change this limit in the configuration.
Also keep in mind that as long as there are 1k-2k results this will work fine but as the number of results increase it becomes increasingly inefficient to get all the results.

Also look at how exactly [pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html) is done in elasticsearch to get an idea of how things work under the hood.

Comment: His "requirement" was to get all docs in "one hit", so that rules out pagination and scan/scroll, unfortunately, even though, admittedly, that's the right way to do it.

Comment: In that case, like i said the only way of doing it in elasticsearch would be to set an absurdly high size (much larger than the number of documents you expect to be in the index).

Comment: I understand now what the question was, will edit the answer.

Comment: That's basically what I suggested to do in my answer ;)